# Python: shapefile.Reader, how to set up .iloc?

Tags: python, shapefile

When I iterate over dataframe or geodataframe and I want to set up some section, I use `df.iloc[0:100]`. How can I set up some section when I use `shapefile.Reader`? For example `0-100` rows.

```
with shapefile.Reader('C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/Praca/Orto_PL1992_piksel3-50cm/PL1992_5000_025') as shp:
    total_rows = shp.numRecords
    for row_num, row in enumerate(shp.iterRecords()):
        print(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

A generator is not subscriptable and `iterRecords()` returns a generator. Instead, use `shapeRecords()` (or `records()`). It gives you a list.

```
rows = shapefile.Reader(shapefile_path).shapeRecords()[0:100]

for row_num, row in enumerate(rows):
    print(row_num, row)
```